# Merge two arrayLists in the correct way to make third arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, updates

i want to use an merged arrayList from two similar arrayLists to make third arraylist to use it as update media. I have been trying to acvieve this for over a week now, but with little progress :(

Given: 1. ArrayList old 2. ArrayList updatedOld 3.ThirdList(mergedList based on 1. and 2.)

Problem: Third arrayList will indicate what has to be removed("*") and what has to be added("!") to whatever it may be. Thouse simbols should be added to to the end of the line(for example "String!").

Example of arraylist 1. and 2.:

1. `1_1_9-A
   1_1_884-B
   1_1_1028-C
   1_1_1030-D
   dd
   2_1_1032-D
   dd
   3_1_1034-D
   dd
   10_1_554-E`
2. `1_1_9-A
   1_1_884-B
   1_1_1028-C
   1_1_1030-D
   dd
   2_1_1032-D
   dd
   3_1_1756-B
   31_1_1603-C
   1_1_1679-D
   da
   2_1_1624-D
   da
   3_1_1714-D
   da
   32_1_1657-C
   10_1_554-E`
3. Vision how third array should look.

`1_1_9-A        equal
1_1_884-B   equal
1_1_1028-C  equal
1_1_1030-D  equal
dd          equal
2_1_1032-D  equal

dd          equal
3_1_1034-D  toBeRemoved
dd          toBeRemoved
3_1_1756-B  added
31_1_1603-C added

1_1_1679-D  added

da          added
2_1_1624-D  added
da          added
3_1_1714-D  added
da          added
32_1_1657-C added
10_1_554-E  equal just changed position but doesnt matter`

I have tried so far determining whitch arraylist is bigger or smaller and based on this information try to compare it to determin if arrays have changed and what values have been removed or added.
Here is the code. I know its not much but it might help:

```
//! - added; * - removed
    //Old is bigger
    if (whosBigger == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < old.size(); i++) {
            if (update.get(i).equals(old.get(i)) && !update.get(i).equals("gap")) { //works
                result.add(update.get(i));
            } else if (!update.get(i).equals(old.get(i)) && !update.get(i).equals("gap")) {
                result.add(update.get(i) + "!");
            } else if (!old.get(i).equals(update.get(i)) && update.contains(old.get(i)) && !update.get(i).equals("gap")) {
                result.add(old.get(i) + "*");
            } else {
                //System.out.println("old: " + old.get(i) + "\n" + "update: " + update.get(i));
            }
        }
    } //update bigger
    else if (whosBigger == -1) {
        for(int i = 0; i < update.size(); i ++){
            if(update.get(i).equals(old.get(i)) && !update.get(i).equals("gap")){
                result.add(update.get(i));
            } else if (!update.get(i).equals(old.get(i)) && !old.contains(update.get(i))) {
                result.add(update.get(i)+"!");
            } else if(update.contains(old.get(i))){

            }
        }
    } //equals
    else {
        System.out.println("they are equal");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution doesn't add the elements in the right order:

You can simply use this on older Java versions:

```
    for(String oldElem : old) {
        if (update.contains(oldElem)) {
            result.add(oldElem + " equal");
        } else {
            result.add(oldElem + " *");
        }
    }

    for (String updateElem : update) {
        if (!old.contains(updateElem)) {
            result.add(updateElem + " !");
        }
    }

    boolean equals = true;
    for (String resultElem : result) {
        if (!resultElem.endsWith("equal")) {
            equals = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (equals) {
        System.out.println("They are equals");
    }
```

I hope the code itself is readable enough to understand it, if not, feel free to ask in the comments.